# Channel Images: Unable to upload images to product entry

Tags: ee2, channel-images

I am having the issue that I am unable to upload any images to the product entry,

The console error I get is:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.findsignage.co.uk/?ACT=38. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://findsignage.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access. admin.php?S=239ef94834e3801b60655ed166061f89f7044695&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id…:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing to do with the Express Store just ExpressionEngine and channel setup and upload manager setup. Check those two first.

Answer (score 3):

The error suggests that you're trying to access content on another domain or sub-domain via JavaScript. Specifically from the information you have provided I think the `www` is the cause of the problem as this is seen as a separate subdomain and not allowed in the cross-origin policy.

Make sure that you pick either `findsignage.co.uk` or `www.findsignage.co.uk` as your fully qualified domain name and stick with it. The debate is out as to which is better to use but it really doesn't make too much difference as long as you're consistent in your choice.

Take a look through your EE config and that set for Channel Images and ensure all references are set to the same location (one of the above). That should resolve the cross-domain origin issue.

Comment: This is indeed a good answer! Had the same issue before. I tried to fix this with htaccess so that if `www.` was not in the url, the mod rewrite would add this. But didn't succeed in setting up my htaccess file correctly! Though it would be a good fix!